# Flying through a country of deportation

Tags: transit, south-africa, deportation

I was recently deported from South Africa and i was given a 12 months ban. I am flying elsewhere using SA airways can i pass through South Africa or i will be deported again on touch down again?

Comment: Will you need to clear Immigration? Would you ordinarily be able to transit SA visa-free? What is your citizenship? A ban would seem to indicate that you can’t transit either and may be denied boarding